# How do I add a dynamic timestamp to a url in HP LoadRunner?

Tags: loadrunner

I would like to add a dynamic timestamp for the URL parameter "time". How do I apply the current time stamp instead of a predefined timestamp?

```
web_url("getSegment.php", 
    "URL=https://somesite.com/getSegment.php?purl=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.example.com%en%2F&jsref=&time=1455031236053", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://stage.example.com/en/", 
    "Snapshot=t3.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [lr_save_timestamp](http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#c_vuser/lrFr_lr_save_timestamp.htm) function:

```
lr_save_timestamp("timestamp", LAST);
web_url("getSegment.php", 
    "URL=https://somesite.com/getSegment.php?purl=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.example.com%en%2F&jsref=&time={timestamp}",
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://stage.example.com/en/", 
    "Snapshot=t3.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);
```